# URL Rewrite issue after submit

Tags: php, increment, auto-increment

I succesfully managed to add to my url an parameter but I can't increment it. For example, if I click on the submit button the url should transform from http://localhost/code/1 to http://localhost/code/2 . I have made an input hidden to access the url but I can't redirect it to the desired value, how can I do this? This is my PHP code:

```
  <?php
  $cod=strtoupper($_GET['params']);
  $i=$_GET['params1'];
  $id_rezervare="SELECT id FROM trezervare WHERE numar_rezervare = '$cod'";
  $id_rezervare = $db->DbGetOne($id_rezervare);
  $cod_rezervare="SELECT UPPER(numar_rezervare) FROM trezervare WHERE numar_rezervare = '$cod'";
  $cod_rezervare = $db->DbGetOne($cod_rezervare);
  $cod_rezervare1 = strtoupper($cod_rezervare);
  $nr_camere="SELECT count(*) FROM trezervarecont WHERE idrezervare= $id_rezervare ";
  $nr_camere = $db->DbGetOne($nr_camere);
  $checkin_status=TRUE;
      $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
      $data_nasterii= $_GET['datanasterii'];
      $test_arr  = explode('/', $data_nasterii);
      if(isset($_POST['trimite'])){
      if (count($test_arr) == 3) {
        if (checkdate($test_arr[0], $test_arr[1], $test_arr[2])) {
      } else {
        $message = "Date has an invalid format";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
      }
    } else {
      $message = "No date selected";
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
}
}
  if(isset($_POST['trimite'])){
    $i++;
  }
        ?>
       <div class="animated fadeOutZoom">
          <div class="container container-sm animated fadeInDown">
            <div class="center-block mt-xl">
              <div class="panel">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <p class="pv text-bold">Check-in for room number <?php echo $i; ?></p>
                  <form action="" method="post">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                        <label for="nume">Nume</label>
                        <input type="text" id="text " class="form-control " name="nume" >
                      </div>
                        <input type="hidden" id="custId" name="checkin_status" value="<?php echo 1;?>">
                        <input type="text" id="custId" name="checkin_status" value="<?php echo $actual_link;?>">

                      <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                        <label for="nume">Data Nasterii</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="arrival_date" name="datanasterii"required/>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                        <label for="nume">Locul nasterii</label>
                        <input type="text" id="text "class="form-control " name="loculnasterii" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                        <label for="nume">Cetatenia</label>
                        <input type="text" id="text "class="form-control " name="cetatenie" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                        <label for="nume">Localitate</label>
                        <input type="text" id="text "class="form-control " name="localitate" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                        <label for="nume">Strada</label>
                        <input type="text" id="text "class="form-control " name="strada" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                        <label for="nume">Numar strada</label>
                        <input type="text" id="text "class="form-control " name="nrstrada" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                        <label for="nume">Tara</label>
                        <input type="text" id="text "class="form-control " name="tara" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                        <label for="nume">Tip act</label>
                        <input type="text" id="text "class="form-control " name="tipact" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                        <label for="nume">Serie act</label>
                        <input type="text" id="text "class="form-control " name="serieact" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                        <label for="nume">Numar act</label>
                        <input type="text" id="text "class="form-control " name="nract" required>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                        <label for="telefon">Telefon</label>
                        <input type="phone" id="telefon " class="form-control " name="telefon" required>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" name="email" required >
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                        <?php if($i==$nr_camere)  echo'
                        <input type="submit" value="Finalizeaza rezervarea" class="btn btn-primary" name="trimite">';
                        elseif ($i>$nr_camere) {
                          header("location:../finalizeaza.php");
                        }
                        else echo ' <input type="submit" value="Continua rezervarea" class="btn btn-primary" name="trimite">';
                        ?>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

                <script>

                //$('#arrival_date, #departure_date').datepicker({format: 'yyyy/mm/dd'});
                $('#arrival_date, #departure_date').datepicker({
                format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                endDate: '+0d',
                minDate: '-120Y',
                autoclose: true
                });


                </script>
```

Comment: Please consider reading [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It took me a minute to even find a submit button... still have no clue what that bunch of code is doing.

Comment: I can't find anything that would send `isset($_POST['submit'])`

Comment: @Jeff submit it's trimite

Comment: exact! Then you check for `isset($_POST['submit'])`?

Comment: Nope, for trimite. If I click on "trimite" which it's the submit button I should be redirected to the incremented value

Comment: just for personal interest: what language is that?

Comment: Romanian, I know, it's a little bit weird :D

Comment: it's not! - ah you've changed the `isset($_POST['submit'])` now. ok.